# How can I shift the orientation of a custom list from vertical to horizontal

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I have a custom list web part that I want to display the members of a team on a custom page.  Instead of listing each name vertically (name is only field I want to display), I would like to display the names horizontally first, then vertical to fill the zone on the page.

This is for display only and typically will only have between 5 to 50 records that need to be displayed.  I have the code now working, but I need more spacing between the columns without effecting any other table in SharePoint.  My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', DisplayMembers);
        function DisplayMembers()
        {retrieveListItems();}

var sectionName = GetUrlKeyValue('Section');
var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl ;
var collListItem
//console.log("Section="+sectionName);

function retrieveListItems() {
console.log("retrieveListItems");
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Contacts');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Section\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>'+ sectionName +'</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>'); 

    collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onmemQuerySucceeded),
                                    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onmemQueryFailed));
}
function onmemQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    var displaytable = "<H1>Members</H1><table>"
    var tblWidth = 3;
    var currentWidth = 1;
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        //console.log("counter currentWidth="+currentWidth);

        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        //console.log("Name="+oListItem.get_item('Title'));
        if (currentWidth == 1){
            displaytable +="<tr><td>" + oListItem.get_item('Title') +"</td><td>"
        } else if (currentWidth < tblWidth){
            displaytable += oListItem.get_item('Title') +"</td><td>"
        } else {
            displaytable += oListItem.get_item('Title') +"</td><tr>"
        }
        if (currentWidth == tblWidth) {
            currentWidth = 1;
        } else {
            currentWidth++;
        }
    }
    displaytable+="</table>"
    $("#pid").html(displaytable)
}
function onmemQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Error: ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
<p id="pid"></p>
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you could add some code.

Comment: I have no code as of yet.  I only have an app web part that displays a custom list.  I didn't know if there was a way to modify the contents of the list to display horizontally, or no app web part and simply pure code to display the list.  Either case, I don't know how, so no code.  Hope this helps.

Comment: its ok, you can add custom code to sharepoint, so try that, if you run into trouble you can edit your question and add your custom code and we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Steve Harvancik,

I believe you're looking for a flex layout. Does below flex box meet the requirement?

```css
.main {  
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.15);
  border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.15);  
}

.item {
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.15);
  padding: 0.5rem;  
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="item">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Flex item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Flex item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Flex item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Flex item 6</div>
  <div class="item">Flex item 7</div>
  <div class="item">Flex item 8</div>     
</div>
```

BR

Comment: should I assume that the first box is inside of a css block?  That seems to work.  Interesting.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need, is flexbox. Inject your custom CSS to your SharePoint page and you'll be good to go.

here is are some links that might help

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/use-css-to-brand-pages